# How to reuse html elements in multiple ASP.NET Core Views?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I have two html div elements. I need to call them seperately multiple times in different. The content of div is coming from parent view model. How to centralize these two divs so that whenever changes to div elements like styling are needed will be done at one place only.  HTML structure of this will be static but content will be from parent view. how to do that? How to do this with minimum load on web server?

Comment: please take a look into partial views, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

As was saying, take a look on Partial Views.
You need to create 2 partial views that contains only this divs and call them in views you need by

```
@{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_YourPartialViewName"); }
```